# Core Plot reload datas from anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, reloaddata

I'm trying to refresh a graph made with `CorePlot` from an other method than `ViewDidLoad` method. The chart view and the graph have been created programmatically in `ViewDidLoad` method. Both are embedded inside a big view.

I have a other method which made some operations to create 3 points that I would like plot on the graph. But, at the end of this method I would like refresh the graph and I don't know what is the way to so.

I tried `[graph reloaData]` method but "`graph`" is not recognized outside `ViewDidLoad` method and I cannot declare `UIview` for the chart view and synthesize it cause it was programmatically created!!!

Comment: possibly add a sample of code to make the example a bit more concrete for folks?

Comment: Sorry but my code is too long for reply. I tried to explain with some parts. In ViewDidLoad, I create my graph like this: //core plot
    CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(377, 246, 384, 512);
    CPTGraphHostingView *chartView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    [self.view addSubview:chartView];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    CPTXYGraph* graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];
    chartView.hostedGraph = graph;
and also datasource and axis parameters. This works fine when i launch.

Comment: How can I add a long post to explain my problem? Comments are limited to 560 characters...

Comment: Hi, i've solved my problem alone.
I've declared CPTXYGraph *graph; in my .h.
And in my .m:
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(377, 246, 384, 512);
    CPTGraphHostingView *chartView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    [self.view addSubview:chartView];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];
    chartView.hostedGraph = graph;
So, the [graph reloadData] method is available from anywhere...